# Route and controller design for vote/like resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I have a like model, recording which user liked which record. I used polymorphic association so a user can like many models.

Currently I use nested-resources to handle likes.

```
POST   /items/:item_id/likes
DELETE /items/:item_id/likes/:id
```

Now for some reasons I want to get rid of the use of `like_id` by designing a better route. This is because it will be easier to cache a fragment view.

Note that `item` model is only one of a few models which are `likable`, and I want to avoid code duplication if possible.

What's a good way to design routes and controllers that will not use `like_id` but also allows better code reuse in controller?

***Possible implementation***

I was thinking of routes like this:

```
POST   /items/:item_id/like
DELETE /items/:item_id/like
```

I won't use nested like resource. Instead I place a `like` action in items controller. It will determine if the request is a `POST` or a `DELETE` and act accordingly. This however doesn't feel DRY.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Rails necessarily, but in Zend Framework I would create a front controller plugin to route all requests with methods 'LIKE' and 'UNLIKE' to a particular controller which then deduces which route was requested, and subsequently which resource was requested, and then performs the necessary actions to 'like' or 'unlike' that resource in the name of the requesting user.

Why? Because the user is 'like'-ing or 'unlike'-ing the resource in question, not 'creating a like' or 'deleting a like'. Sure, in the backend, the 'like' is a record in a cache or database that gets created or deleted -- but the semantics of a resource are not necessarily equivalent that of whichever method is used to persist that resource.

Comment: I think you have got a point. Let me see what the Rails equivalent is.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Singular Resources.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :items do 
  resource :like, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

**likes_controller.rb**

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :load_likeable

    def create
        @like = Like.where(likeable: @likeable, user: current_user).first_or_create
        redirect_back(fallback_location: @likeable)
    end

    def destroy
        @like = Like.find_by(likeable: @likeable, user: current_user).destroy
        redirect_back(fallback_location: @likeable)
    end

    private

    def load_likeable
        klass = [Recording].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"] }
        @likeable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
    end

end
```

**likes_helper.rb**

```
module LikesHelper

    def like_button_for(item)
        if item.liked
            form_tag recording_like_path(item), method: :delete do
                button_tag "UnLike"
            end
        else
            form_tag recording_like_path(item), method: :post do
                button_tag "Like"
            end
        end
    end

end
```

*item.liked is method from Item model*